# Is "help" a causal verb?

Tags: computational-linguistics

As part of my research, I extract causal (cause-effect) relations from natural text. Sometimes, there are words in the text that signal a causal relation like "*because*" or "*since*." And, some other times, there are some *nouns* or *verbs* (or words with other part of speeches) that signal such relations.

I am wondering if you think "**help**" signals a causal relation (based on your knowledge of language and semantic)? For example, when we say "*x helped y to happen,*" can we infer that x is the cause for y to happen?

A real world random example, "**UBR4 helps neurons divide in the brains of children.**" In this case, can we say "**UBR4**" is somehow the cause for "**neurons to be divided**?"

As another example, with a different but similar verb, "The roar was caused by the injection into the aircraft’s four afterburners of the fuel which provided the extra thrust that it needed to take off." can we conclude that "***provide***" signals a causal relation and "*the injection into the aircraft’s four afterburners*" is the cause of "*the extra thrust?*"

Generally, I am trying to figure out if I can use "help" or "provide" as signals for causal relations in text.

Comment: Not always. Consider "I helped my children do their homework", well they would have done it without me.